# flutter/firebase, how can I verify the email without entering a password?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make a loggin system that allows to signIn/signUp (with google or facebook) and then add a verified phone number, and vice versa. If I enter the email first and then the phone number I have no problems since the email is verified. but in the opposite case, first I enter the phone number and then I update the email, but this time I enter the values (mail and displayname) through a TexFormField. Because of this the emailVerified parameter always starts at false. I tried to use the sendEmailVerification method but according to the documentation, the verification  email is only sent for users created with the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method. Which does not help me since I do not want to start with email and password but with phone number, I only want email (verified) and displayName for reference.

I use the following code (firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.Instace):

1. I get the verification sms

```
await firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: Constants.timeOut),
        verificationCompleted: (_) {
          ...
        },
        verificationFailed: (firebaseExcep) {
          ...
        },
        codeSent: (verificationId, _) {   <--------- here
          setVerificationId(verifycationId);
          completer.complete('ok');
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (_) {
          ...
        },
      );
```

2. After receiving the sms I start the session with that phone number

```
final credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId: verifycationId, smsCode: smsCode);
await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

3. Then I enter email and displayName and update the previously created user:

```
await firebaseAuth.currentUser!.updateEmail(email);
await firebaseAuth.currentUser!.updateDisplayName(name);
```

--- Up to this point I have in firebase a user with phone number, email and displayName. But emailVerified is false

4. Finally, I try to send the verification email but I never receive anything

```
firebaseAuth.currentUser!.sendEmailVerification()
```

--- According to the documentation it is because this user was not created with createUserWithEmailAndPassword. Is there any other way to check the email?

Answer (score 0):

I was literally writing a multi-step signup page passwordlessly. I have looked up and I don't think **sendVerificationEmail** would work.